# Kustomize: no matches for kind "Kustomization" in version "kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1"

Tags: kustomize

I am new to Kustomize and am getting the following error:

Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Kustomization" in version "kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1"

but I am using the boilerplate kustomization.yaml

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- deployment.yaml
- service.yaml
```

Question:  What does the group name (kustomize.config.k8s.io) mean and why does Kustomize not recognize the kind?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

So this api version is correct, although I am still not certain why.  In order to get past this error message, I needed to run:

```
kubectl apply -k dir/.
```

I hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 12):

If you used `apply -f` you would see this error. Using `-k` would definitely work.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `kustomize` tool (`Kustomize` is a standalone tool to customize the creation of Kubernetes objects through a file called `kustomization.yaml`). For applying customization you have to use:

```
kubectl apply -k foldername(where you store the deploy,service yaml file)
```

Answer (score 0):

My case is different. My kustomization is new version and "-k" option still is using old version of kustomize. I installed a new version of kustomize in environment. I run the following commands and it wokrs.

```bash
 kustomize build dir/. | kubectl apply -f -
```